# css sprite for scaled background svg in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-sprites, antialiasing

I wanted to use scaled svg images as icons of different sizes, but found inconsistent behaviors in firefox.

Without css sprite, firefox would anti-alias the scaled images. But with css sprite, firefox would not anti-alias them. Therefore, The icons looked ugly with css sprite.

Please visit this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX4ej/) for details. What's the problem with firefox?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ1oF.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style type='text/css'>
.whole {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url("outliner.svg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
i {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("outliner.svg");
    background-size: 500% 500%;
}
.circle { background-position: -32px 0;}
.disk { background-position: 0 -16px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>With CSS Sprite:</div>
<i class="circle"></i><i class="disk"></i>
<div>Without CSS Sprite:</div>
<i class="whole"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no CSS method to change the rendering mode of SVG elements, though there is an SVG attribute that can do so: [`shape-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering).

I went ahead and [ran your SVG file through a base64 encoder](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) (which you can use to *decode* the data in the following examples), after adding `shape-rendering: <value>` to each of your `<g>` elements, where `<value>` has several options: [`optimizeSpeed` (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/VX4ej/14/), [`crispEdges` (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/VX4ej/12/), and [`geometricPrecision` (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/VX4ej/13/).

Depending on how you want your final SVG to display, just choose one of the particular values, and your final SVG code will look somewhat like the following (note the `shape-rendering` attribute on each of the `<g>` tags):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="480" height="480" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
<g shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#333" fill="#333">
  <g shape-rendering="crispEdges" id="icon-1-1" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="86" y2="86" stroke-width="12"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="86" x2="86" y2="10" stroke-width="12"/>
  </g>
  <g shape-rendering="crispEdges" id="icon-1-2" transform="translate(96,0)">
    <!-- svg continues below ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks. But no matter which option I choose, the icons with css sprite still look uglier than those without css sprite.

Comment: @Z.H. Actually, now that I take another look at the CSS sprites against the non-sprite version from your original example, [they look exactly the same](http://i.imgur.com/GhJbCfu.png). That image is what they look like after taking a screenshot and zooming in to 4x normal (when viewed in Firefox 25).

Comment: Oh, It seems that Firefox team has been fixed this bug. I am using Firefox 17 ESR.